# Delete text block with regexp in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

Textfile contains blocks:

```
<tr>
    <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
    <td>//div</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>assertElementPresent</td>
    <td>//div</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

I want to remove all blocks with regexp in notepad++ with the word assertElementPresent in it:

```
<tr>*assertElementPresent*</tr>
```

who can help me with the regular expression??

Comment: Regex is not very useful for HTML parsing; are those other strings (`//div` etc.) always the same, or can they vary? (I'm sorely tempted to close this as a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags )

Comment: I don't think he cares about parsing it... this is a text editor, after all.

Comment: @BoltClock: I'm not sure I noticed that in the initial version; it is possible I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

```
<tr>.*?assertElementPresent.*?</tr>
```

should be a good start (note the ungreedy matches), however, it's rather brittle.

Comment: It should not matter whether they're greedy or ungreedy, but this should work.

Comment: @BoltClock: Regexes will match greedy by default - so if you're matching across lines, it would match the first `<tr>`, then most of the text, then assertElementPresent, then the rest of the text, then the very last `</tr>`. Probably not what the OP wanted.

Comment: it does not work.. because the regexp needs to search over more lines

Comment: @Daan: there should be a "multiline" option somewhere; not sure how exactly it's implemented in Notepad++, but most regex-capable tools have it (append `/m` ???).

Comment: This is where it gets complicated... :) There is no multiline option. As much as I love Notepad++ its regex support is hopeless.

Comment: @BoltClock: hmm...I was wondering if it had anything near POSIX regex capabilities.

Comment: @Piskvor: I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: When it has not changed with the last release, then Notepad++ is not able to handle multiline regex. Regex support only within one row.

Answer (score 1):

```
<tr>(?!.*<tr>.*).*?assertElementPresent.*?</tr>
```

It has been tested with [RAD](http://www.radsoftware.com.au/regexdesigner/) and [RegExr](http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/). The previous suggested solution picks the previous row also..

Comment: NOtepad++ does not support multiline regex and look ahead/behind assertions.

Comment: Within Notepad++ I don't know a solution for this problem.